# Website effects using Python. HTML and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, python-3.x, frontend

please forgive my lack of experience with regard to the following question, and understand I'm asking from the perspective of someone very new to the whole front-end development paradigm.

My question revolves primarily around this website effect:

[codepen_link to website effect](https://codepen.io/mrspok407/pen/NRxBWa)

I'm nowhere near experienced enough to know the answer to this question, hence me reaching out to the community.

My question is, in a nutshell; "would it be possible to achieve the same website effect seen in the above link, but instead using Python as opposed to JS?"
(primarily because I'm in the middle of a Python journey, and I'm interested in the possibilities)

I've been attempting to Google various website effects using Python, but to no avail, hence me reaching out for a more experienced perspective.

While I understand that this may be easier achieved with JS, I'm (perhaps naively) asking for comments from people with the relevant experience to chime in and help guide me with the above.

Thank you all for your help, it's very much appreciated and again, apologies for my lack of experience.

(apparently I need to add some code in order to post the question, so here's a snippet of the JS code from the link above, apologies if this isn't the correct etiquette:)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    const $app = $('.app');
    const $img = $('.app__img');
    const $pageNav1 = $('.pages__item--1');
    const $pageNav2 = $('.pages__item--2');
    let animation = true;
    let curSlide = 1;
    let scrolledUp, nextSlide;
    
    let pagination = function(slide, target) {
        animation = true;
        if (target === undefined) {
            nextSlide = scrolledUp ? slide - 1 : slide + 1;
        } else {
            nextSlide = target;
        }
        
        $('.pages__item--' + nextSlide).addClass('page__item-active');
        $('.pages__item--' + slide).removeClass('page__item-active');
        
        $app.toggleClass('active');
        setTimeout(function() {
            animation = false;
        }, 3000)
    }
    
    let navigateDown = function() {
        if (curSlide > 1) return;
        scrolledUp = false;
        pagination(curSlide);
        curSlide++;
    }

    let navigateUp = function() {
        if (curSlide === 1) return;
        scrolledUp = true;
        pagination(curSlide);
        curSlide--;
    }

    setTimeout(function() {
        $app.addClass('initial');
    }, 1500);

    setTimeout(function() {
        animation = false;
    }, 4500);
    
    $(document).on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(e) {
        var delta = e.originalEvent.wheelDelta;
        if (animation) return;
        if (delta > 0 || e.originalEvent.detail < 0) {
            navigateUp();
        } else {
            navigateDown();
        }
    });

    $(document).on("click", ".pages__item:not(.page__item-active)", function() {
        if (animation) return;
        let target = +$(this).attr('data-target');
        pagination(curSlide, target);
        curSlide = target;
    });
});
```

Comment: The code you've shared does not involve any Python - but that is not a surprise, as Python does not run in the browser usually. Try to write your markup using JS and CSS first, and use Python later if neccessary

Comment: Maybe skip the JS/Python dilemma and go straight for CSS - perhaps a CSS mask image of the right shape animated?

Comment: If you look at the code in the codepen it actually has an img of which the top half looks like the shape you need as a mask.

Comment: Yes, there are various project that allow you to program in Python. But I do not recommend it. It will not help you on writing Python nor web. You will need to use Python in a non-standard way (so you risk to get bad habits). And web is built on DOM which is language independent, in theory. It will be much easier if you use direct JavaScript. Learning multiple language is good (and you do not need full JavaScript). And so you separate the styles together with languages. Again: JavaScript in web is used in a particular way.